# Symlink a plugin in local development, works but got Debug error message - Windows 10

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I read that WP 3.9+ supports symlink ([Article here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/14/symlinked-plugins-in-wordpress-3-9/)).

So, my plugin resides in `C:\Github\my-plugin`. while my project is at `C:\Project\my-site`.

I successfully symlink it by using this command (run as admin):

```
mklink /d C:\Project\my-site\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin C:\Github\my-plugin
```

The symlinked plugin **WORKS** but I got this debug message on ALL pages:

```
Warning: fopen(C:/Project/my-site/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/C:/Github/my-plugin/index.php):
failed to open stream: Invalid argument in
C:\Project\my-site\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4568

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
C:\Project\my-site\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4571
```

As you can see the path detected by WordPress is a merge of my-site and my-plugin and thus it can't read the file. But weirdly, the plugin runs fine.

**Anyone successfully symlinked a plugin in Windows 10?**

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

Found the issue. I hosted my plugin on Github and has a snippet I found online to enable update via admin panel.

The snippet has hardcoded directory so it doesn't detect symlinked url.

Comment: if the plugin works, were does the error come from?

Comment: I tried symlinking another plugin and this one works without debug error. I'll check if there's issue with the first one.

Comment: Mind updating the question with the relevant info?

Comment: @MarkKaplun Sorry, found the issue. I have specified it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the root cause, but you should avoid using relative paths to files. Because they are relative you never sure where exactly a file is being looked after. It might even become a security risk as PHP might look for the file in the default directories.

The proper way is to use the [plugin_dir_path](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/), something like

```
require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'github-updater.php';
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll change all my requires to this. Also, I found that the issue lies in the code snippet I used has hardcoded directory like `$dir . '/' . $slug`. That can be fixed with the snippet above.